# How do I hide scroll bar by default

Tags: html, css

I am using the following CSS to provide scroll bar when window is re-sized. I have two problems. One is the vertical scroll bar is visible by default. I want it to appear only if window is re-sized. I have tried with different heights but that didn't go. Second problem is when window is re-sized, the background color of the part of div which is viewed after scrolling is not applied. How do I fix these? This is my CSS and div

```
    <div class = "gridclass" id="grid1" jsid="grid1" dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid"
            query="{ name: '*' }"data-dojo-props="plugins:{ pagination:{pageSizes: ['10', '25', '50', '100'],
            description: true, sizeSwitch: true, pageStepper: true, gotoButton: true, position: 'bottom', maxPageStep: 7}}, rowsPerPage:10"></div>
    </div> 

    #grid1{
       overflow-x:auto;
       overflow-y:auto;
       height:60%; 
       width: 106.5%;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set overflow: hidden; on the body tag :

```
<style type="text/css">
body 
{
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

To hide only the vertical scrollbar, use `overflow-y:` 
To hide only the Horizontal scrollbar, use `overflow-x:`

```
<style type="text/css">
body 
{
overflow-y:hidden; or overflow-x:hidden
}
</style>
```

**Second Problem :** 
Try this one..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CwS4/2/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop()<800){
$('#fixed').css('background-color','Yellow');
}else{
$('#fixed').css('background-color','White');
}
})
```

Comment: what about my second problem?

Comment: are you using a reset css? maybe the body tag is being overriden, @JavaBeginner ?

Comment: I have updated the second problem try that one... @JavaBeginner

Answer (score 0):

css style:

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

and javascript:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').css({'overflow':'auto'});
});
```

Comment: background color problem?